# Unity-BuildFailedException:BurstCompiler(1.1.1) Failed Running

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, game-development

Hello I Installed Unity After I Build A Simple Game After i wanted to Build My Game
I Tested Build and Build and Run ,I Dont Have Visual Studio beacause I Cant Download It
I Use Visual Studio Code To Coding unity
I Cant Download Visual Studio
When I Click Build After Seconds Give Me:
Image:https://s6.uupload.ir/files/annotation_2022-07-31_143005_dctf.jpg

Comment: Welcome to SO!  However _large title case paragraph hits you for 50 damage!_ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed Not Needed to install Visual Studio only :

1. Project settings > Burst AOT Settings > Disable Burst Compilation > ON